# iOS 13 presentation style default

Tags: ios, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

In my iOS app I have about 60 `present(_:animate:complition)` calls from legacy code.

iOS 13 just changed the default `presentationStyle` to `Automatic` which actually means `.formSheet` style.

Is there a quick way to change the default back to `.fullScreen` on all the app? maybe like in the infoPlist or some global protocol like `UIAppearance` Protocol? If there's no way i need to set the `presentationStyle` manually in 60 places...

Comment: Don't change the default. Users expect the new look. Use it, don't fight it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it doesn't fit the design I need fullScreen for this app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no global variable to override to change this. This is all part of updating for the new OS's! Embrace the change, and change them all manually. This helps with code management and future proofing the app too. A small headache now which can help in the long run.

Comment: I hope you're wrong... for me, this is no small headache or a legitimate one. no offense but I will wait a few more days before accepting this answer :)

Comment: This is the correct answer though. cmd + shift + F and update your calls. No way around it

Comment: @ozd unfortunately programming isn't always sunshine and lollipops! They love making our lives a hardship.